# Calling mremap in Go doesn't work, but gives no error

Tags: linux, go, unix, system-calls, mmap

I'm trying to `mremap` a file from Go, but the size of the file doesn't seem to be changing, despite the returned `errno` of `0`. This results in a segfault when I try to access the mapped memory.

I've included the code below. The implementation is similar to the `mmap` implementation in the [`sys`](https://go.googlesource.com/sys/+/master/unix/syscall_unix.go#107) package, so I'm not sure what's going wrong here:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"

    "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
)

// taken from <https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/f8394f232b1eab649ce2df5c5f15b0e528c92091/include/uapi/linux/mman.h#L8>
const (
    MREMAP_MAYMOVE = 0x1
    // MREMAP_FIXED     = 0x2
    // MREMAP_DONTUNMAP = 0x4
)

func mremap(data []byte, size int) ([]byte, error) {
    header := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&data))
    mmapAddr, mmapSize, errno := unix.Syscall6(
        unix.SYS_MREMAP,
        header.Data,
        uintptr(header.Len),
        uintptr(size),
        uintptr(MREMAP_MAYMOVE),
        0,
        0,
    )
    if errno != 0 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("mremap failed with errno: %s", errno)
    }
    if mmapSize != uintptr(size) {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("mremap size mismatch: requested: %d got: %d", size, mmapSize)
    }

    header.Data = mmapAddr
    header.Cap = size
    header.Len = size
    return data, nil
}

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lshortfile)
    const mmPath = "/tmp/mm_test"

    // create a file for mmap with 1 byte of data.
    // this should take up 1 block on disk (4096 bytes).
    err := ioutil.WriteFile(mmPath, []byte{0x1}, 0755)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // open and stat the file.
    file, err := os.OpenFile(mmPath, os.O_RDWR, 0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    stat, err := file.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // mmap the file and print the contents.
    // this should print only one byte of data.
    data, err := unix.Mmap(int(file.Fd()), 0, int(stat.Size()), unix.PROT_READ|unix.PROT_WRITE, unix.MAP_SHARED)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("mmap data: %+v\n", data)

    // mremap the file to a size of 2 blocks.
    data, err = mremap(data, 2*4096)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // access the mremapped data.
    fmt.Println(data[:4096]) // accessing the first block works.
    fmt.Println(data[:4097]) // accessing the second block fails with `SIGBUS: unexpected fault address`.
}
```

I tried looking for other Go code that uses `mremap`, but I can't seem to find any. I would appreciate any input!

Comment: I don't know go, but IIRC in C you'd have to grow the underlying file with `ftruncate()` or whatever before extending the memory mapping.

Comment: My first thought would be to `strace` it to make sure the `mremap` call is issued and interpreted correctly

Comment: The `mremap` works for me (Linux 4.19.0, amd64) but I'm with @Shawn on this: [you first need to increase the file](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.os.linux.development.system/c/l1ZNR5Pq4Ws) and then resize its mapping to cover the addition, not the other way round. Just verified that adding `file.Truncate(2 * 4096)` before `mremap` fixes the problem.

Comment: Calling truncate before mremap fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Also was asked [over there at `r/golang`](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/jqy3n4/trouble_calling_mremap_from_go/).

Comment: @EarlyEarthworm, consider answering an accepting your own question: that's absolutely OK on SO (and is actually encouraged as the users may specifically search for questions with accepted answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kostix mentioned in the comments, `mmap` is being used to map a regular file into memory. The reason that accessing the buffer results in a segfault is that the underlying file itself is not large enough. The solution is to truncate the file to the desired length before calling `mremap`:

```golang
if err := file.Truncate(2*4096); err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
data, err = mremap(data, 2*4096)
```